# MySQL select from * between < xx > minutes

Tags: mysql, select, time, between

I need help with select date timestamp from MySql tabel between tow values.
Like:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE time >= NOW() - 60 MINUTES AND <= NOW() + 120 MINUTES
```

I can't select right.

Comment: For programs TV, program can start at 07:00 and end at 09:00 but now is 08:00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATE_SUB` and `DATE_ADD`

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
    AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 120 MINUTE)
```

Comment: can he use like this `SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE time >= (NOW() -60)  AND time <= (NOW() - 120)` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You can't add and subtract from times that way .. pretty sure

Comment: but I believe its a valid SQL expression.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It's a valid expression, but so is `'STRING' - 10`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [addtime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) and [subtime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN 
SUBTIME(NOW(),'0 1:0:0') AND ADDTIME(NOW(), '0 2:0:0')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE time >= SUBTIME(now(),'1:0') AND <= ADDTIME(now(),'2:0');
```

see here for manual [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)